# Function to create xts object from keyboard input

Tags: r, function, input, xts

I have lots of sales areas.  Each one is a data.frame and I can create xts objects for each.
This requires a line of code for each.  I'd rather use a function to create on demand.
I've tried using keyboard entry to create a character string, then strip the quotes and store the input as symbol, to be used in a function.  This doesn't work!

```
## Function to specify unit
userinput <- scan("", what="")
userinput <- as.name(userinput[1])

## Function to create xts object
createXts=function(x) {
  xts(x[1], order.by=x$StartTime, dateFormat="POSIXct")
}
## Call function
createXts(userinput)
##Result:
>> Error in x[1] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

How can I use user input to specify a data.frame to be used in a function? Note: The `createXts` function does work if I replace `x` with a real unit's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
CreateXts <- function () {
  xx <- scan("", what="")
  xx <- get(xx[[1]])
  xts(xx, order.by=xx$StartTime, dateFormat="POSIXct")
}
```